# SDL_MouseButtonEvent is behaving like SDL_MouseMotion

Tags: c++, c, graphics, 2d, sdl

I coded an application but got erroneous outputs from SDL. To specify my problem, I have developed a simple code to count the number of clicks from mouse. I am using CodeBlocks with GCC compiler on Windows.

The code goes as follows :

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc , char *args[] )
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL ;
    SDL_Renderer *render = NULL ;
    SDL_Event event ;
    int counter = 0 ;

    SDL_Init ( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) ;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow ( "" , 0 , 0 , 400 , 400 , SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS ) ;
    render = SDL_CreateRenderer ( window , -1 , SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED ) ;

    // Putting white color over window
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor ( render , 255 , 255 , 255 , 255 ) ;
    SDL_RenderClear ( render ) ;
    SDL_RenderPresent ( render ) ;

    counter = 0 ; //Reinitializing counter to 0

    //Starting Input
    while ( 3 )
    {
         SDL_PollEvent ( &event ) ;
         if ( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP )
         {
               counter++ ;
         }
         else if ( event.type == SDL_KEYUP )
         {
               if ( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
               {
                     break ;
               }
         }
    }

    // Actual Clicks = 2
    printf("CLicks = %d" , counter );

    return 0 ;
}
```

The Output Always Is Fairly Huge & Erroneous. The sample output is posted at

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2krxxnuHys0UzB3Q1d3MzJEVVU

Comment: Would you delete that Google Drive link please, and move the output into the question? Since the question is reliant on that link, we do not want to risk the data being deleted, since that would mean we would have to delete the question. Remember that questions here are intended for posterity, not just for the original poster.

Comment: Please also read: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SDL_PollEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) doesn't block until event happens but instead returns 1 if it written event data into given structure, or 0 otherwise. You're ignoring this value and reading data from event anyway; noone said this event data is valid, especially first time, since it wasn't even initialised.

Check return value and only use event if SDL said event is indeed happened. You can also use `SDL_WaitEvent`, which blocks until event happens.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: I know that would be tedious but please

Comment: I finally got hang of what you wanted to say buddy. Thanks a lot. Project is on!!! Anyways, for other users, put `if(!(SDL_PollEvent(&event))continue;` in while loop  in the beginning  & see wonders. Remove the normal 'SDL_PollEvent(&event)`. Thanks again.